# jQuery form validation, show success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The following jQuery is working very well, now I am trying to show a success message, but I can't get it to work. This is my attempt.

```
            jQuery("#name").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL)  return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter more than 5 characters",
                success: function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("ok");
                }
            });
```

I would like to show a `div` with the class 'ok'.

This is the div

```
<div class="ok"> OK! </div>
```

and this is the css

```
.ok { display: none; color: green; }
```

Comment: Are you using the validate plugin defined here ? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: @WalterStabosz I don't think this is that validation plugin, or if it is, I don't see any reference to this `expression` option...

Comment: @Ryley I noticed that too about the 'expression' option. I guess we'll just have to wait for Maarten to clarify.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks. Yes I'am using the jquery.validation plugin, but this was a remake.. now I'm using the right one, where this function was already built in :) for others having the same problem use this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ Thanks again for all your help guys

Comment: @MaartenHartman you can add your own answer to your question (and even accept it), i.e. explaining how you changed your code to make it work... people will even upvote it for you :)

Answer (score 4):

```
.ok { color: green; }
```

Remove display:none from your css, (move it to the DIV's style attribute so you can toggle it with jQuery)

```
<div id="successMessage" style="display:none;" > OK! </div>
```

Then make your success method:

```
success: function() {
     $('#successMessage').show();
}
```

I don't know the validate() method well, so I'm not sure what $(this) refers to inside of the success method, so I used an ID selector. See the documentation for [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: This is the way to go (deleted my answer).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but it is still not working. I'm afraid the problem lies somewhere else. Will be continued, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if i understand correctly, you are very close!

just give your div an id:

```
<div id="successMessage" class="ok"> OK! </div>
```

then in your validate instead of using this, select your div by id:

```
$("#successMessage").show();
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, please read the comment above! :)